# How do I display a validation message when the switch control value is changed to True in Angular?

Tags: angular

How do I display a validation message when the switch control value is changed from False to True?

```
 form: new FormGroup({}),
 fields: [
      {
        key: 'value',
        type: 'switch',
        templateOptions: {
           label: 'Basic'
        },
        expressionProperties:{
           'templateOptions.required': 'model.value',
        },
         validation: {
          show: true,
          messages: {
            required: 'Price is required' 
          }
        },
        wrappers: [
          'sersi-form-field'
        ]
      }
    ],
    model: { value: false}
  }
```

Comment: Is this switch its own formcontrol? If so you could subscribe to its valueChanges and check if the value is true and present a message when it is. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges

Comment: yes, Is there an example you can post please?

Comment: I found a example by a developer named Cory Rylan where I just simply added the subscription to valuechanges can you check if you can see it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqcgc1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) . In that example you can also see how he retrieves the current value if you look in the submit() method which you also would be able to use to display a message in the template.

Comment: No problem! Did you get it to work?

Comment: yes, I added validators.                                                                                                             validators: {
          validationMessage: {
            expression: (control: FormControl) => control.value === false,
            message: 'Validation message is displayed here'
          }
        },

Comment: Tommi, can you please help me with this issue too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388707/disabled-checkboxes-in-angular-formyl

Comment: I can try but I havent worked with angular-formly, I just use the built in reactiveform. But I asked a couple of questions in your other issue.